# How to aggregate distinct values of one key then sum the matching values of the other key?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-queryset

I've made a loop that gives me data in the following format:

```
name_quant = [{'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '1'}, {'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '2'}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '1'}, 
 {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '2'}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '2'}, {'name_id': 'S00002', 'quantity': '1'}]
```

I used the following loop to get the values above:

```
namesequence = EventSequence.objects.filter(description="names").values("Details")

name_quant = [{ 'name_id': e['element'][33:39], 
                        'quantity': e['element'][50:51] } for e in namesequence ]
```

So my question is how can I aggregate the name_ids and sum the quantities of matching name_ids so that i get a result like so:

```
 name_sum = [{'name_id': 'S00001', 'quantity': '160'}, {'name_id': 'S00002', 'quantity': '50'}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '40'}, {'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '90'}]
```

I would have used the sum function in Django but I have to subscript and loop though the value first which makes it a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it looks like the requirement is to consolidate keys (name_id) by quantity. I can't see how the required output values are derived from the sample input data but that may be because it's incomplete.

```
name_quant = [{'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '1'}, {'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '2'}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '1'}, 
 {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '2'}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '2'}, {'name_id': 'S00002', 'quantity': '1'}]

td = dict()

for e in name_quant:
    nid = e['name_id']
    td[nid] = td.get(nid, 0) + int(e['quantity'])

new_list = [{'name_id': k, 'quantity': str(v)} for k, v in td.items()]

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '3'}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '5'}, {'name_id': 'S00002', 'quantity': '1'}]
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i was lookign for! and I should have made the example output  match the input.. but I just added large numbers to give the impression that the input would actually be much larger than the example input I gave... thanks!!

Comment: your answer came out faster when using perf_counter() !

Answer (score 2):

If the list of name_quant is large, I prefer to use pandas to do the groupby staff:

```
import pandas as pd

name_quant = [{'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '1'}, {'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': '2'},
              {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '1'},
              {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '2'}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': '2'},
              {'name_id': 'S00002', 'quantity': '1'}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(name_quant)
df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].astype(int)
results = df.groupby(['name_id']).agg({'quantity': 'sum'}).to_records()  # [('S00002', 1) ('S00003', 5) ('S00004', 3)]
grouped_name_quant = [{'name_id': x[0], 'quantity': x[1]} for x in results]
print(grouped_name_quant)
```

The output is :

```
[{'name_id': 'S00002', 'quantity': 1}, {'name_id': 'S00003', 'quantity': 5}, {'name_id': 'S00004', 'quantity': 3}]
```

Comment: This would surely be the ideal way to do it if the `name_quant` list is large. Note to OP, try both the answers and evaluate the performance using `time.perf_counter()`. Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-perf_counter-function-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks for this solution!! I'll try both and see what happens.. There are over 5000 name_id to group so you're solution may be the most ideal!

Comment: Yours took seconds: 0.041820599988568574 whereas the other script took  0.03718249994562939..... Not what I was expecting but cool to know! The total quantity of all name_ids were 91,000 and the max quantity of one name_id could have is less than 10.. so there were MANY name_ids haha

Comment: your's worked perfectly aswell!

Comment: I see, if your name_id is not so many, then use name_id as buckets and aggregate will be quick. Maybe generating dataframe and dict is slow.